# How do I save a TFDV stats in the correct format for them to be loaded back in?

Tags: tensorflow-data-validation

It is puzzling to me that there is a `tfdv.load_statistics()` function, but no corresponding `tfdv.write_statistics()` function. How do I go about saving the statistics, and then loading them again?

e.g.

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_dataframe(df)

# how do I save?


# load back for later use
saved_stats = tfdv.load_statistics('saved_stats.stats')
```

I can save the string representation to a file, but this is not the format that load_statistics expects.

```
with open('saved_stats.stats', 'w') as o:
    o.write(str(stats))
```

Pointers anyone?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this : tfdv.utils.stats_util.write_stats_text ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say I probably didn't, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In the current `tfdv` version *1.3.0* there are the following methods that can be used:

- [load_stats_text](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/api_docs/python/tfdv/load_stats_text)
- [write_stats_text](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/api_docs/python/tfdv/write_stats_text)

Example:

```py
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv

stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_dataframe(df)
stats_path = "my-stats-file.stats"

# saving
tfdv.write_stats_text(stats, stats_path)


# loading
stats = tfdv.load_stats_text(stats_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay figure out this hacky way to do it.

```
df = ... # create pandas df
from tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0 import statistics_pb2
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_dataframe(df)

# save it
with open('saved_stats.stats', 'wb') as o:
    o.write(stats.SerializeToString())

# load back for later use
with open('saved_stats.stats', 'rb') as i:
    loaded_stats = statistics_pb2.FromString(i.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called `tfdv.load_stats_binary` that you can use to solve this problem.